# How to create life cycle in S3 aws

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created one bucket in S3 and I want create life cycle as 1 day delete objects condition, I already created the condition as below.

Expire current version of object: **After 1 days from object creation**

Permanently delete previous version: **After 1 days days from becoming a previous version**

But this condition not working. I created the  folder on 23/06, but on 25/06 it is still showing in my S3 bucket. Can you help on this.

[image: Lifecycle configuration]

Comment: The lifecycle does not necessarily run at a particular time or duration. Give it another day to see whether it works. I recall reading something that said you won't be charged for storage, even if it isn't deleted yet.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Thanks for your reply, I am already created two life cycle rules another one is Expire Current version of object After 2 days from object creation.